# Golang sha256 hash not satisfying okta code challenge

Tags: go, okta, pkce

I'm using golang to implement the PKCE authentication flow against Okta. Okta needs a url-safe string of at least 43 characters (the verifier), then calculate a sha256 hash, which is sent as base64 URL encoded (the challenge). [Okta PKCE Flow](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-auth-code-pkce/use-flow/)

I generate a random verifier. Here's a sample: `aAOzSsxfONaAauKYKRABWUfZLFgVFZqgbJRaArwKAzhzEWurUAhDyzcTkSKLClFL`

To generate the base64 encoded sha256 sum:

```golang
        hasher := sha256.New()
        hasher.Write([]byte(login.CodeVerifier))
        codeChallenge := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
```

When given the sample `verifier` above produced a challenge: `1XvaG5_-p9OPfxH9yeLmSWu5zGHxW6Pjq_HrdSsI-kk=`

yet upon completing the POST against `/token` endpoint always returns the error:

```
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "PKCE verification failed."
}
```

And this is the logic to POST to `/token`:

```golang
        code := r.URL.Query().Get("code")
        state := r.URL.Query().Get("state")
        log.Debug().Msgf("callback code:%s state:%s verifier:%s", code, state, loginCache[state])

        values := url.Values{}
        values.Set("grant_type", "authorization_code")
        values.Set("client_id", clientID)
        values.Set("redirect_uri", redirectURI)
        values.Set("code", code)
        values.Set("code_verifier", loginCache[state])

        request, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", oktaTokenURL, strings.NewReader(values.Encode()))
        request.URL.RawQuery = values.Encode()
        request.Header.Set("accept", "application/json")
        request.Header.Set("cache-control", "no-cache")
        request.Header.Set("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

        response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
```

Comment: The program encodes  `values` to the request body and the request query string. Are both needed and is that possibly causing a problem?

Comment: Also: Do not modify the URL after creating the request (while this might be perfectly okay it is ugly as hell. Or maybe wrong.)

Comment: `request.URL.RawQuery = values.Encode()` was not supposed to be there.  As a POST, there was not supposed to be query string values.  However, removing the line did not change the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Golang, but I believe the issue is that you are using the wrong functions to bas64 encode. [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) states

```
Base64url Encoding
      Base64 encoding using the URL- and filename-safe character set
      defined in Section 5 of [RFC4648], with all trailing '='
      characters omitted (as permitted by Section 3.2 of [RFC4648]) and
      without the inclusion of any line breaks, whitespace, or other
      additional characters.  (See Appendix A for notes on implementing
      base64url encoding without padding.)
```

Looking at the [base64 documentation in Go](https://godoc.org/encoding/base64#RawSTDEncoding), `var RawStdEncoding = StdEncoding.WithPadding(NoPadding)` should output the correct format.

> RawStdEncoding is the standard raw, unpadded base64 encoding, as defined in RFC 4648 section 3.2. This is the same as StdEncoding but omits padding characters.

Comment: this was a great idea, but I couldn't get it to work. I saw the method you referenced, but no change in the error message.

Comment: Perhaps I'm late and probably you already fixed it, but just in case, I think what's needed here is `base64.RawURLEncoding`.